# PrestaShop module classes not found (namespaces)

Tags: php, namespaces, prestashop, webhooks

This is my PrestaShop module file structure:

```
-mymodule/
--src/
--mymodule.php
---Presta/
---Webhooks.php
----Controller/
-----MyPrestaController.php
```

mymodule.php cannot find Webhooks.php class, I've tried use in mymodule.php, but still it provides errors:

```
ClassNotFoundException in mymodule.php line 55:
Attempted to load class "Webhooks" from namespace "src\Presta".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

When I try to use autoload/include/require in mymodule.php it throws fatal errors, because autoload initialize stuff(from my module vendor) that shouldn't be initialized in mymodule.php. GuzzleClient gets crazy while browsing website:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to 
GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, 
called in /usr/local/ampps/www/presta/modules/mymodule/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 89 and defined
```

I don't want to put all hook logic in mymodule.php and I have other classes that I need to implement in webhook methods. Is there any way to use other classes in main module file(mymodule.php)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of prestashop and how are you calling Webhooks class?

Comment: 1.7.3 and example Webhook class called in:

    public function hookActionAuthentication($params)
    {
    Webhooks::myStaticWebhooksMethod($params);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your class with full path or declare a `use` on top of your module file. I don't know exactly what namespace `Webhooks` is under but something like this:

```
public function hookActionAuthentication($params) 
{ 
    \src\Presta\Webhooks::myStaticWebhooksMethod($params);
}
```

or

```
use src\Presta\Webhooks; // before module class declaration

public function hookActionAuthentication($params) 
{ 
    Webhooks::myStaticWebhooksMethod($params);
}
```

Comment: Finally I used require_once in mymodule main file, presta doesn't like custom namespaces and there is problem with use. But the main reason I was getting errors was conflict between mymodule GuzzleHttp6 and prestaShop GuzzleHttp5 lib, had to remove GuzzleHttp from my module and use the core presta one.

Comment: @maciey_b In PrestaShop files such as module or controller classes I call my custom classes with full namespace path and I use composer's PSR-4 autoloader. And yea those library conflicts is what's called a dependency hell.